# Unformatted USB stick, access from console?

Tags: usb, mount, devices

When I install an *unformatted* (technically it is formatted in a weird file system from an embedded system) USB stick into my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I receive the following in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 22 22:22:12 host kernel: [10288570.860788] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 22 22:22:12 host kernel: [10288570.886451] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05dc, idProduct=a83a
Jun 22 22:22:12 host kernel: [10288570.886457] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 22 22:22:12 host kernel: [10288570.886460] usb 2-2: Product: USB Flash Drive
Jun 22 22:22:12 host kernel: [10288570.886463] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Lexar
Jun 22 22:22:12 host kernel: [10288570.886466] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: [REMOVED]
Jun 22 22:22:12 host mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2"
Jun 22 22:22:12 host mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 2 was not an MTP device
```

I would like to access the raw data from the USB stick as a block storage device. That is, I would like to be able to do `dd if=/dev/xxx of=file.out`.

Unfortunately, the device does not show up as any block device, e.g., `lsblk -a` does not list it, nor any other command dealing with block devices. It shows up fine under `lsusb` and `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2` though.

How can I force the stick to become a block device using the command line?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you don't see any `/dev/sdX` devices in there?  an unformatted USB will show as a device without partitions, and `lsblk` might not show it if there is no partition table on the device.

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. Running, say, `lsblk -a` only lists `sda`, which is my internal drive. Even when I 'brute force' `sdb[123]`, `sdc[123]`, ... nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the system was running for some time and apparently the current kernel modules were accidentally uninstalled.

After doing an `apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-XX` for the currently running kernel it just worked.